# spring security redirect user by ROLE

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want to redirect user to a page based on his ROLE but i don't know how to do it.
I serched all over but it doesn't work for me. It's taking the redirect for ROLE_MASTER even if the user has ROLE_USER or other.
I tried in different ways as you can see in the commented code but none of them worked correctly.

the code is:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UsersDetailsServiceImpl usersDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("stefan").password("1234").roles("ADMIN");
        auth.userDetailsService(usersDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/res/**");
    }

    //.csrf() is optional, enabled by default, if using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter constructor
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http    .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/master/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_MASTER')")
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
                .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
                .antMatchers("/viewer/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_VIEWER')")
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/").failureUrl("/?error")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").defaultSuccessUrl("/master")
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
                .and()
                .csrf();

//                .and()
//                .authorizeRequests()
//                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
//                .and()
//                .formLogin().loginPage("/").failureUrl("/?error")
//                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")
//                .and()
//                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
//                .and()
//                .csrf()
//
//                .and()
//                .authorizeRequests()
//                .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
//                .and()
//                .formLogin().loginPage("/").failureUrl("/?error")
//                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").defaultSuccessUrl("/user")
//                .and()
//                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
//                .and()
//                .csrf()
//
//                .and()
//                .authorizeRequests()
//                .antMatchers("/viewer/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_VIEWER')")
//                .and()
//                .formLogin().loginPage("/").failureUrl("/?error")
//                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").defaultSuccessUrl("/viewer")
//                .and()
//                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
//                .and()
//                .csrf();


//        http.authorizeRequests()
//                .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
//                .and()
//                .formLogin().loginPage("/").failureUrl("/?error")
//                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")
//                .and()
//                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
//                .and()
//                .csrf();

//        http.authorizeRequests()
//                .antMatchers("/user/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
//                .and()
//                .formLogin().loginPage("/").failureUrl("/?error")
//                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").defaultSuccessUrl("/user")
//                .and()
//                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
//                .and()
//                .csrf();

//        http.authorizeRequests()
//                .antMatchers("/viewer/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_VIEWER')")
//                .and()
//                .formLogin().loginPage("/").failureUrl("/?error")
//                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password").defaultSuccessUrl("/viewer")
//                .and()
//                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/?logout")
//                .and()
//                .csrf();
        //  http.formLogin().loginPage("/admin/login").failureUrl("/admin/login?error").defaultSuccessUrl("/main",true).usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password");

    }

}
```

any ideea how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own  `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` check user role from `authentication`  object and send redirect to suitable URL

```
<bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="..." />
<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" ... />
```

[full example with roles](http://www.baeldung.com/spring_redirect_after_login)